# Pass List<string> from ActionResult to partialview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `ActionResults` and I want to pass a list string to a `partialview`, but I just cannot work out how to do it.

Hopefully someone a lot cleverer :-) than me can help me solve it.

```
namespace Web.UI.Controllers
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
{
    var currentConditions   = await Task.Run(()=> _IGWC.CurrentConditions("194.61.173.5").FirstOrDefault());
    var weatherAstronomy    = await Task.Run(()=> _IGWC.WeatherAstronomy("194.61.173.5").FirstOrDefault());
    var weatherConditions   = await Task.Run(()=> _IGWC.WeatherConditions("194.61.173.5").FirstOrDefault());
    var weatherLocation     = await Task.Run(()=> _IGWL.WeatherSearch("194.61.173.5").FirstOrDefault());

    string test      = currentConditions.feelsLikeC.ToString();
    string test1     = weatherAstronomy.sunRise.ToString();
    string test2     = weatherConditions.maxtempC.ToString();
    string test3     = weatherLocation.DisplayAreaName.ToString();

    List<string> weatherData = new List<string>();
    weatherData.Add(test);
    weatherData.Add(test1);
    weatherData.Add(test2);
    weatherData.Add(test3);

    return PartialView(weatherData);
}
```

In my index view which contains the partialview I have:

```
@{Html.Partial("Test","Home");}
```

And finally in my partialview I have tried using the following.

```
What goes here

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
@item.
}
```

How can I get the values from `weatherData` and pass to partialview, the only way I have found for it to work is using tempdata, but I do not want to go down that route.

---------------------------Code Update----------------------

In index view I have put the following as requested:

```
  @model System.Collections.Generic.List<string>

@{Html.Partial("Test", Model);}
```

In partialview I have the following:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>


<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@item</li>
}
</ul>
```

This now results in the following error:

Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object. caused by @foreach (var item in Model)

Answer (score 1):

Your not far away, you just need to tell the view what type of model to expect e.g.

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<string>

<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@item</li>
}
</ul>
```

**Update**

Looking at your code you seem to be getting confused between the difference of rendering a view and actually invoking a controller action. When you call `Html.RenderPartial` you are asking MVC to directly render that particular *view*, not invoke the action on the controller. `RenderPartial` expects the second parameter to be the model for that view (if it applicable) - your view is expecting a `List<string>` but your passing in "Home" which is a string which is why you are getting errors along the line of:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'

What you need to do is actually invoke the *action* and render the resultant view e.g.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Test", "Home"); }
```

Comment: Hi James I get the following error Message=The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

Comment: @CareerChange you are passing "Home" in as the model to your partial view, you need to pass in the `Model` e.g. `Html.Partial("Test", Model)`. I think you are getting confused with trying to render a partial view (which won't go to the controller) and actually calling a controller action.

Comment: Hi James this is what i have Line 15: @{Html.RenderPartial("Test", Model);}, have also tried Line 15: @{Html.Partial("Test", Model);} but get the same error as I put down for Aaron and Bennor

Comment: Return type of RenderAction is void, you'll need `@Html.Action("Test", "Home")`. But don't do this in your "test" view or you'll infinitely recurse.

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy good spot, I have updated my answer. The OP is calling this inside the Index view, not the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your partial view define

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
```

In your view that is rendering your partial view add

```
@{Html.Partial("Test", Model);}
```

Comment: Hi Aaron and Bennor I have tried what you have said and get the following error: System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'Partial' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: Odd. You might need to put `@model System.Collections.Generic.List<string>` at the top of your index view as well.